# Groovy - Use XmlSlurper with a dynamic path

Tags: groovy

Is it possible to access a node of Xml using an arbitary path?

Eg: Given the xml:

```
    <records>
      <bike name='Chopper' />
      <car name='HSV Maloo' make='Holden' year='2006'>
        <country>Australia</country>
        <record type='speed'>Production Pickup Truck with speed of 271kph</record>
      </car>
      <car name='P50' make='Peel' year='1962'>
        <country>Isle of Man</country>
        <record type='size'>Smallest Street-Legal Car at 99cm wide and 59 kg in weight</record>
      </car>
    </records>
```

How do I access the contents of the xml using an arbitrary path, provided as a string -- eg:

```
XmlSlurper xml = new XmlSlurper.parse(theXml)
assert xml['bike.@name'] == 'Chopper'
assert xml['car[0].country'] == 'Australia'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One method is to use [the `Eval.x` static method](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/Eval.html#x%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) to evaluate a String;

```
def xml = '''|    <records>
             |      <bike name='Chopper' />
             |      <car name='HSV Maloo' make='Holden' year='2006'>
             |        <country>Australia</country>
             |        <record type='speed'>Production Pickup Truck with speed of 271kph</record>
             |      </car>
             |      <car name='P50' make='Peel' year='1962'>
             |        <country>Isle of Man</country>
             |        <record type='size'>Smallest Street-Legal Car at 99cm wide and 59 kg in weight</record>
             |      </car>
             |    </records>'''.stripMargin()

// Make our GPathResult    
def slurper = new XmlSlurper().parseText( xml )

// Define our tests
def tests = [
  [ query:'bike.@name',     expected:'Chopper' ],
  [ query:'car[0].country', expected:'Australia' ]
]

// For each test
tests.each { test ->
  // assert that we get the expected result
  assert Eval.x( slurper, "x.$test.query" ) == test.expected
}
```

Comment: Actually, although this is cool, I don't really understand why this works - specifically the tokens `$test` and `query` in Eval. Why `$test` and not `${test}`)?  Also, is `query` a method defined against the `GPathResult`?  If not, where does it come from?

Comment: @MartyPitt `test` is from our `each` function, so the first time round it is equal to the map `[ query:'bike.@name',     expected:'Chopper' ]`.  So, `"x.$test.query"` (which is identical to `"x.${test.query}"`) gets evaluated to the String `"x.bike.@name"`.  `Eval.x` sets `x` to be the `slurper` instance, and then evaluates the expression.  Then, it does the same again with the second map in our list `[ query:'car[0].country', expected:'Australia' ]`...  Hope this explains it?

Comment: Yep, crystal clear.  Must've been late last night!  Thanks again.